# How can I make jQuery resizable() prevent overflow?

Tags: jquery, resize, overflow, resizable

I have a set of resizable div which can dynamically have content added to them. My problem is that the content inside the div will overflow outside the dimensions of the box.

I do not want to use overflow: auto, but instead always make sure that the div is large enough to fit the content inside of it so that it cannot be resized smaller.

Does jQuery provide some simple way of doing this?

The current code is below

```
$(this).draggable().resizable(
{
  minWidth: 200,
  minHeight: 150,
  maxWidth: 600,
  maxHeight: 450,
});
```

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/#max-min

Comment: I am already using minWidth and minHeight, the problem is that the div can still be resized to that value even if the content is greater

Comment: btw, remove the last comma :)

Comment: could you try removing the draggable() ? And what is $(this) ? How do you get it ?

Comment: but, where is it "called". `this` means that it's an argument in a function call, right ? What's the whole function ?